# Debugging asp.net service with Android device and Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome

I have setup with VS2012, running an ASP.net web service which talks to an SQL database. I also have an android app being developed (using Cordova, so using javascript) which talks to this web service via ajax.
Everything works fine when I run the javascript on a desktop browser, and most most calls to the web service work fine between the app (loaded onto a phone) and the production server (when I upload the server files there). But there is one service call that doesn't work, and it depends data from Cordova plugins so I have to debug it using the phone and I need to see what's happening at the server end in VS2012 instead of on the production server. I have installed Chrome Dev Tools, and set up port forwarding as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#port-forwarding) but can't make the connection; every json call results in "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in the Chrome console. I have tried turning off the firewall on the PC (Windows 7) but no effect.
This must be a common requirement and it seems from the Chrome Dev page that it is all straightforward so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use an emulator? I find that works well though I don't use Cordova or Chrome tools.

Comment: Thanks, an emulator can represent some Cordova plugins but I'm using Bluetooth functions to get data via radio, so must use the actual device.